# Why does this regex execution not return the match

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group

My regex is:

```js
let a = new RegExp("(?:https?:)?\/\/(?:www\.)?(?:facebook|fb)\.com\/(?<profile>(?![A-z]+\.php)(?!marketplace|gaming|watch|me|messages|help|search|groups)[\w.\-]+)\/?", "g")
```

It's basically a modification of the one seen [here](https://github.com/lorey/social-media-profiles-regexs#facebook) for facebook to extract the username from a facebook url.

My test string is `https://facebook.com/peterparker` and my code is:

```js
a.exec("https://facebook.com/peterparker")
```

When I try this in [RegExr](https://regexr.com/), it works fine. It shows the correct group captured (`peterparker`).

[image: regexr behaviour]

Yet, when I try the same code in Google Chrome's console, the code returns null:

[image: google chrome console]

Why doesn't it show up in the chrome console?

Comment: The "Named capture groups" feature may not be supported on all browsers. Did you try on other browsers?

Comment: can you try to save c.exec in a variable something like var test = exec("https://facebook.com/peterparker") and then do test or console.log(test) ?

Comment: @SamilKahraman RegExr uses the same code so it definitely was not a browser issue.

Comment: @Marcogomesr Yes, didn't make a difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're creating your regex from a string, you have to escape your backslashes.

```js
let a = new RegExp("(?:https?:)?\/\/(?:www\.)?(?:facebook|fb)\\.com\/(?<profile>(?![A-z]+\\.php)(?!marketplace|gaming|watch|me|messages|help|search|groups)[\\w.\\-]+)\\/?", "g")
console.log(a.exec("https://facebook.com/peterparker"))
```

Creating it inline does not have this problem.

```js
let a = /(?:https?:)?\/\/(?:www\.)?(?:facebook|fb)\.com\/(?<profile>(?![A-z]+\.php)(?!marketplace|gaming|watch|me|messages|help|search|groups)[\w.\-]+)\/?/g
console.log(a.exec("https://facebook.com/peterparker"))
```

Comment: This was it. Thank you. Was driving me crazy